# The mesh contains self intersecting faces after mesh smoothing

Tags: intersection, mesh, smoothing

all

I obtain an triangle mesh after the reconstruction process. To remove the noise, I try to smooth the mesh.
Some triangles appear dark in MeshLab after the smoothing operation. The smoothing operation will move the positions of the vertices. The motion will cause intersection and normal inconsistency. I think it is inevitable for all smoothing methods. Am I correct? Is any postprocessing required?

Regards
Jogging

Comment: What kind of smoothing did you use?

Comment: Thanks. Do you the mean the specific smoothing method. I try to use MLS(Moving least square) smoothing. I think any kind of smoothing may result in non-manifold mesh if the input mesh is manifold.